Tabularray with footnotes inside a tcolorbox/ minipage
This question is related to Tabularray with footnotes and the new thing is that my tblr-tables are sometimes inside of tcolorboxes. The style of the numbering then goes wrong and counting up the footnote doesn't work either. The footmarks inside the tcolorbox should appear in italic \alph style. The following things go wrong:

footnotemark after "bbb" is "7" and has to be an italic "b". The analogue
applies from "ccc" to "eee". Here is the wrong counter in use: wrong
is "footnote", right is "mpfootnote"
Normal footnotemark after "fff" has the right style, but has to be
an italic "f"
Footnotemark after "seven" has to be an arabic "7". This is a
subsequent error from using the wrong counter inside the tcolorbox.

My wishes:

The items in 1, 2 and 3 should be corrected.
There should be one command \footNote for use in tblr-tables that is usable in the case of tcolorboxes-environments (or more generally in minipage-environments) and in normal cases (non-minipages). An automatic situation switching would be really helpful so that you don't have to adjust all the footnote commands when moving the table to a tcolorbox or vice versa. How to recognize the respective situation (i.e. whether you are in a colorbox/minipage or not) is beyond my current knowledge. The commented out command \stepcounter{mpfootnote} is partially successful, but is not correct because both counters are then always incremented. Also, the style of the footnote markers is wrong in the table inside the tcolorbox, they should be italic letters.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray, tcolorbox}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\UseTblrLibrary{functional}

\makeatletter
\IgnoreSpacesOn
\tlNew \gFootNoteTl
\intNew \gFootNoteInt
\prgNewFunction \footNote {m}
{
    \tlPutRight \gFootNoteTl
    {
        \stepcounter{footnote}
        %\stepcounter{mpfootnote}
        \footnotetext{#1}
    }
    \prgReturn {\footnotemark{}}
}
\AddToHook{env/tblr/before}{
    \intSetEq \gFootNoteInt \c@footnote
    \tlClear \gFootNoteTl
}
\AddToHook{env/tblr/after}{
    \intSetEq \c@footnote \gFootNoteInt
    \tlUse \gFootNoteTl
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    Some normal footnote one\footnote{note one}.
    
    \bigskip
    
    \begin{tblr}[evaluate=\footNote]{colspec={ll},hlines}
        a line & two\footNote{note two}\\
        another line & three\footNote{note three}
    \end{tblr}
    
    \bigskip
    
    \begin{tblr}[evaluate=\footNote]{colspec={ll},hlines}
        a line & four\footNote{note four}\\
        another line & five\footNote{note five}
    \end{tblr}
    
    \bigskip
    
    Some normal footnote six\footnote{note six}.
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white,colframe=red, title={A tcolorbox}]
        Some normal footnote aaa\footnote{note aaa} before.
        
        \begin{tblr}[evaluate=\footNote]{colspec={ll},hlines}
            a line & bbb\footNote{note bbb}\\
            another line & ccc\footNote{note ccc}
        \end{tblr}
        
        \bigskip
        
        \begin{tblr}[evaluate=\footNote]{colspec={ll},hlines}
            a line & ddd\footNote{note ddd}\\
            another line & eee\footNote{note eee}
        \end{tblr}
        
        Some normal footnote fff\footnote{note fff} after.
    \end{tcolorbox}
    Another normal footnote seven\footnote{note seven} after.
    
\end{document}



Would it be possible to use \TblrNote instead of footnotes in your tabularray environments?

@Mane32 \TblrNote ist only for longtblr. I would like the developer to ensure that \TblrNote also works in the normal tblr environment. longtblr chops up the table in a tcolorbox and is therefore unusable there. I think longtblr doesn't expect to work in any limited environment like a minipage.

it also work with talltblr environments.
